# Besides Proto-Indo-European, does any language have separate words for "one alone" and "one united"?

Tags: proto-indo-european, comparative-linguistics, numerals

In PIE, ***e̯oinos*** meant "one alone", "one separated", it has the same root as in the word for "goes", ***e̯eiti***. Semantically it meant the one that went away.

At the same time, ***som*** meant "one united", "all as one", "together" and had the same root as the reflective pronoun meaning "self".

That is, the first meant one thing of a set or quantity while second meant the whole set as a unity. In a sense these words were antonyms.

Do any other languages have similar opposition?

Comment: That PIE had those two roots is widely accepted. That they might originally have had different meanings is plausible. But what is your evidence for the specific meanings you give, and for the derivations? They sound highly speculative to me.

Comment: Latin had a similar distinction between "solus" and "ipse".

Comment: I second Mr. Fine's question, but because I do not know ***e*** (and I know that you don't work with laryngeal notation so I expect others would write \*h1 in the front). I do agree with the *separate, united* notion, though I can't derive it. If reading "one" as personal pronoun, pretty much any language contrasting 1st p. sg. with e.g. 1st p. pl. or *ya'll* qualifies as answer; I'm not sure whether to consider the in-/animate distinction, though, "goes" implies animate. Thinking of *summon* I remember that *summit* and *zenit* came through Semitic. *self* rather reflects \*se, \*sel-, no?